# MongoDB and Mongoose - One to Many Relationships

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, one-to-many

I'm having a devil of a time understanding the one to many relationship options in MongoDB. I have a fairly simple use-case that I want to prove out, and I can't seem to find any good step-by-steps with my Google (and Stack Overflow)-Fu.

If I access mongo's command line tool, insert a document into the "users" collection with a String array of role_id that corresponds to the _id in the "roles" collection ... how do I tie all of it together on the mongoose side? When I use the findOne method, it just seems to pull the "role_id"s as is, so I know I must be missing something.

If I put all of these roles into the users without any reference what so ever, what happen if I needed to enable or disable roles? Would I need to update every single relevant role in every single user?

Thanks muchly for the assistance and patience for another new Mongoer!

Comment: Since mongodb doesn't really handle "joins" in the way sql does, you have to send two requests to get that data. One to get the users, and then another to get all the roles of all those users. Luckily mongoose does this for you when you use the .populate method.

Comment: Populate! That's what I've been missing! I had no idea that existed. Thank you, @KevinB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your explanation you just forgot to use 'populate' in your query. Please note that results will not contain linked  document, so you need to use 'populate' in order to let mongoose know - 'Hey, I want to pull info about this role as well'.

Example:

```
//promises
User
  .findOne(<searchQuery>)
  .populate('roles')
  .exec()
  .then(function(foundUser){
      return foundUser; //do something with results (foundUser)
  })
  .onReject(function(err){
      throw err; //do something with error
});

//callbacks
User
  .findOne(<searchQuery>)
  .populate('roles')
  .exec(function(err, foundUser){
      if(err){
          throw err; //do something with error
      } else {
          //do something with results (foundUser)
      }
});
```

Please check the following links:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html
- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html